# Meta Keywords Optimization Best Way to Proceed?

Tags: seo, best-practices, meta-keywords

I am on a wallpapers blog project... When i generate leech pages I put in the tags about that image in meta information... But i also need to tell that these are wallpapers...

So what is the best way to do it...

like for an iron man wallpaper i would do this

```
<meta name="keywords" content="iron , man , tony , stark" />
```

***Should I be adding wallpapers to the keywords?...***

Comment: Keep in mind that this will have absolutely no effect on your SEO as the search engines do not use the meta keyword tag anymore. If you want to have your pages rank better or better indicate what their content is about be sure to put content on those pages and tag advantage of the page title and heading tags.

Comment: i am already doing that... i went through the google page rank checklist...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
<meta name="keywords" content="iron man, iron man wallpaper , wallpaper" />
```